# gnome-terminal-server: Locale not supported

Tags: locale, gnome, manjaro

I recently installed manjaro gnome and after configuring locale settings, I found out that the terminal does not show up due to this error (from journalctl -xe):

```
(process:2410): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling 
StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited 
with status 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX:

So I went over internet and searched the error. I found out that it has something to do with /etc/locale.gen and /etc/locale.conf

It's actually on gnome's side and for whatever reasons related to their glib, they self-generated a corrupt locale.conf file and line "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" in file /etc/locale.gen has remained commented; so I uncommented that line and ran:

```
    $ sudo locale-gen
```

After that, I edited line "LANG=en_US.utf8" to "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" in /etc/locale.conf file.

Finally, I ran gnome terminal and it came up!